# Scrollview with snapping and scaling

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview, paging, scaling

I've been wanting to make a scrolling snapping scaling UI for a Swift iOS app for a bit now, but never knew what to search for. Then last night I was in the Apple News app and saw this, which is EXACTLY what I want to do. Any pointers on where to start?

I've made a scrollview with paging before, but this requires every "page" to be the same size, and I only ever see the current page. I like how you can see like 10% of the page to the left and right while on the current one. Additionally, I want the centered "page" to be larger than the outside ones.

Is there a name for this type of scrolling animation? Not knowing what it's even called has made searching difficult.

Thanks!

GIF:

[image: slider]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a UICollectionView implementing what is popularly known as a "Carousel".

It's actually *very* easy to implement as a UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass with just a few simple tweaks. You just have to override three methods:

- `shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange:)` to `true`, to get layout during scrolling
- `layoutAttributesForElements(in:)` to modify the `transform3D` property of the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes for the onscreen cells
- `targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity:)` to get the paging effect

Apple explains it all to you in a WWDC 2012 video. IIRC they call it "Cover Flow" because it's modeled after cover flow in the Mac Finder.

Comment: Holy cow! That was incredibly helpful. Searching "uicollectionview carousel" lead me to this, which is exactly what I'm talking about. This is perfect! https://github.com/ink-spot/UPCarouselFlowLayout I would have never guessed it was a collection view, though it makes sense.